# How to post same URL parallel multiple time with different params using angular 4 / angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular5

How to post same URL parallel multiple time with different params using angular 4 / angular 5 and return data ?.

i have a multiple get request

```
let value = Array();    
    let character = this.http.get('https://sameURL');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('https://sameURL');
    value.push(character);
    value.push(characterHomeworld);
    forkJoin(value).subscribe(results => {      
      (results[0] as any).homeworld = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
    });
```

the above code is for HttpGet. I need to post the sameURL multiple time with parameters

Comment: Please explain what you're trynna say

Comment: i have a url which i need to post with a parameter . i need to post this url multiple times

Comment: Please mention the use-case with some code snippet.

Comment: Highly confusing what is the url ,Where you want to post ,What have you tried till now

Comment: Assume a sample URL to post........... i have modified the question please re check

Comment: hai @BlackMamba

Answer (score 1):

**CASE 1**: Assuming that you want to POST (multiple times) the same url with **different query params** such as:

- 'https://sameURL?id=0'
- 'https://sameURL?id=1'
- ... then:

  `let value = [];

        let character = this.http.post('https://sameURL?id=0');
        let characterHomeworld = this.http.post('https://sameURL?id=1');
        value.push(character);
        value.push(characterHomeworld);
        forkJoin(value).subscribe(results => {

          results[0]; // response from REST call with id=0
          results[1]; // response from REST call with id=1
        });`

**CASE 2**: Assuming that you want to POST (multiple times) the same url with **different body** such as:

- 'https://sameURL' --> body: {id: 0}
- 'https://sameURL' --> body: {id: 1}
- ...
  then:

  `let value = [];

    let character = this.http.post('https://sameURL', {id: 0});
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.post('https://sameURL', {id: 1});
    value.push(character);
    value.push(characterHomeworld);
    forkJoin(value).subscribe(results => {

       results[0]; // response from REST call with body {id: 0}
       results[1]; // response from REST call with body {id: 1}
    });`